# How to use a wilcard for email address?

Tags: php

`if ($email != "user@domain.com")` but with a wildcard before the @ sign.

Something like `if ($email != "*@domain.com")`

Comment: maybe use `strstr()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if(preg_match('/^.+@domain\.com$/', $email))
```

Comment: This works in the sense that it is a wildcard for an email address.  The way I am trying to use it is to remove the wildcard address.  This removes all of the other email addresses and keeps only the wildcard one.  How do I reverse that?

Comment: `if(!preg_match('/^.+@domain\.com$/', $email))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_a_match = (strpos(strrev($email), strrev('@domain.com')) === 0);
```

Comment: Explanation: If the reversed @domain.nl string is at the beginning of the reversed email string, it is actually at the very end of the original string. I am not sure if this is the smartest way of going about things, but it works.